# Can "because of" be followed by "how"?

Tags: grammar

I was wondering if 'how' can be used after 'because of'?

Is this redundant or entirely wrong? While I don't think it's correct I am not certain either.

Comment: Your question is not clear because of how you asked (it).

Answer (score 3):

It is not redundant, and it is not wrong. For instance, you can say "I won the race **because of the way** I drove." Of course here, **the way** and **how** are interchangeable, and reads "I won the race **because of how** I drove."